# Minkowski functional being homogeneous

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $(X,\|\|)$ a normed vector space over $K$ and $E\subset X$ convex and absorbing. Let $p_E(x)=\inf_{x\in tE}\{t>0\}$, $E_1=\{x\in X:p_E(x)<1\}$ and $E_2=\{x\in X:p_E(x)\le 1\}$. I want to prove that:
$$
\text{If  }E\text{  is balanced}\Rightarrow p_E(\alpha x)=|\alpha|p_E(x)\;\forall \alpha\in K\;\;\forall x\in X
$$
If $\alpha\ge0$ is clear that $p_E(\alpha x)=|\alpha|p_E(x)\;\forall \alpha\in K\;\forall x\in X$. So lets assume $\alpha<0$
If $\alpha$>-1, then 
$$-\alpha E\subset E$$
So, for $x\in E$, 
$$-\alpha x\in E\Rightarrow p_E(-\alpha x)\le 1\Rightarrow -\alpha p_E(x)\le 1\Rightarrow -1\le\alpha p_E(x)$$
but got stucked here. I don't know if this is the right way to do it and can't figure out how to make $p_E(\alpha x)\le |\alpha| p_E(x)\le p_E(\alpha x)$. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: $\alpha p_E(x)\le 1$ is trivial if $\alpha < 0$.

Comment: Ok, now I got that $|\alpha p_E(x)|\le 1\;\;\forall x\in E$

Comment: Why do you mention $E_1$ and $E_2$ in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it.

Let $x\in X$ and let $\alpha\in K$.

---

***Lemma:$\;\;\forall x\in X,\;\;p_E(-x)=p_E(x)$*** 

Let $x\in X$ and let $\epsilon>0$, so 
$$
\exists\;t>0 \text{  s.t.  } t<p_E(x)+\epsilon\;\; \land\;\; x\in tE
$$
so, since $E$ is balanced,
$$
\frac{1}{t}x\in E\Rightarrow -\frac{1}{t}x\in -E\subset E\Rightarrow p_E(-t^{-1}x)\le 1\Rightarrow p_E(-x)\le t
$$
thus
$$
p_E(-x)<p_E(x)+\epsilon\;\forall \epsilon>0
$$
so
$$
p_E(-x)\le p_E(x)
$$
and applying this last result to $x=-x$ we get that $p_E(x)\le p_E(-x)$.

---

If $\alpha <0$ we have that $|\alpha|=-\alpha$ and by the Lemma we get that:
$$
p_E(\alpha x)=p_E((-\alpha)(-x))=-\alpha p_E(-x)=|\alpha|p_E(x)
$$